# How to do some work before async task finish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am new to study about `asyncio`.I don't know how to 
describe my question.But here is a minimal example:

```
import asyncio

async def work():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def check_it():
    task = asyncio.create_task(work())
    await task
    while True:
        if task.done():
            print("Done")
            break
        print("Trying...")

asyncio.run(check_it())
```

---

My idea is very simple:

1. create a async task in `check_it()`.And await it.
2. Use a `while` loop to check whether the task is finished.
3. If `task.done()` return `True`,break the `while` loop.Then exit the script.

If my question is duplicate, please flag my question.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `asyncio.wait` or use `asyncio.sleep`. Otherwise, your program will output a lot without some pauses.

```
import asyncio


async def work():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)


async def check_it():
    task = asyncio.create_task(work())
    # "await" block until the task finish. Do not do here.

    timeout = 0 # Probably the first timeout is 0
    while True:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait({task}, timeout=timeout)

        if task in done:
            print('Done')

            # Do an await here is favourable in case any exception is raised.
            await task

            break

        print('Trying...')
        timeout = 1


asyncio.run(check_it())
```